# Getting rid of blocking code

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, blocking, autoresetevent

I am not sure if I can explain it well here but let me give it a try. Code below is just to show the idea as I am just typing it here without verifying everything in the compiler.

I have a method (say Method1) where I am doing two things.
1. Calling a web-service method to perform an action. 
2. After that, I am polling on same web-service object to wait until action results become available.

So basically something like as follows.

```
public class MyClass   
{   
  Method1()   
  {     
    // call Web service method  

    // code for polling    
  }  
}
```

However this approach makes Method1 blocking until action results become available as determined during polling. I want to change it such that caller of Method1 can return immediately after call to web service method and can somehow be signaled once web-service results are available. So I am thinking of having a AutoResetEvent object as class member that I set to signaled state during polling.

```
public class MyClass   
{   
  public AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
  Method1()   
  {     
    // call Web service method  

  }  

  Method2()   
  {     
    // code for polling    
    // change state of autoEvent to signaled once results are availble

  }  

}
```

With this approach, user of this API just call Method1 that returns immediately and they can just do wait on autoEvent to get signaled. The problem is that who is going to call Method2 in this case?

Comment: If you're going to wait on something, you're going to block, regardless of whether it's in method 1 or method 2.  Something is blocking when you wait on the event.  The real problem here is that you don't appear to understand how asynchrony works in .NET at all, and are just making it up as you go along.  I suggest you start by reading up on the Begin/End Asynchronous pattern, and if you can use .net 4.5 then read up on async/await

Comment: I'd be inclined to simply let `Method1()` block.  If that is a problem for the caller then that is where it should be handled, e.g. using a separate thread with whatever synchronization method is appropriate at the higher level.

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your comments. I do have to admit I am quite new to asynchrony pattern. I will definitely read about your suggested topics but are you suggesting that I can implement Begin/End Asynchronous pattern here. For now I will have to stick to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of different methodologies for asynchronous code. The most common in .NET today is to utilize [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). For a basic example you can do something like:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
task.ContinueWith(() => DoAfterSomething());
```

This allows the code to continue processing while the task is executed on a background thread. This might seem a bit wordy & clumbsy with all the lambdas and sub-methods, which is why the async\await pattern was introduced. This looks something like:

```
Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    // do something asynchronously..
}

async Task<int> ExampleAsync()
{
   int result = await DoSomethingAsync();
   DoAfterSomething();
   return 42;
}
```

Note that DoAfterSomething may be called on a different thread than the original caller.

Another methodology that is commonly used is the [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) methodology. This involves two methods that kick off an async thread and another to complete it (usually BeginX and EndX). This commonly looks like:

```
FileStream fStream = /* etc */
byte[] buffer = /* etc */
void ReadFile(FileStream fStream)
{
    var asyncResult = fStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0 , buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(EndReadCallback), null);
}

void EndReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    int length = fStream.EndRead(result);
    // continue processing on buffer
}
```

Another methodology is the [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) model which uses events to trigger completion. This model isn't used much in the .NET framework, but it is in there. It is used something like:

```
WebDownload download = /* etc */
download.DownloadComplete += (buffer) => { /* do something with buffer */ };
download.Get("http://foo/img.jpg");
```

Personally, I use async\await for everything I create, but the other methodologies are good to know in case you encounter them in legacy components. If you ever need to convert APM or EAP to task based, you can do this pretty easily with [Task.Factory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) or using [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx)